# How to avoid loading for nonexistent static pages?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ssg

I'm making e-commerce Next.js static app.

For my products pages I'm using incremental static generation (I'll call it ISG further) with `fallback: true` and simple `useRouter` for showing loading component (like spinner or something else, it doesn’t matter). ISG is very useful function for static sites with frequent updating data (like adding comments, new products and so on), but if I don't have product path (for example `/products/nike-pants-12345`) the page will return "infinity loading" and error.

The error is below.

[image: Error with non-exist page for ISG]

If we take a look in console we can see something like: `TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null`. It means that app didn't find product with requested _id (it could be name, slug and so on).

So, the question is how I can avoid this case and should this one be avoided at all?

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    await dbConnect()

    const products = await ProductModel.find({})

    const paths = products.map((doc) => {
        const product = doc.toObject()
        return {
            params: { id: product._id.toString() }
        }
    })

    /* fallback: true means that the missing pages
    will not 404, and instead can render a fallback */
    return { paths, fallback: true }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    await dbConnect()

    const product = await ProductModel.findById(params.id).lean()
    product._id = product._id.toString()

    // revalidate set the time (in sec) of re-generate page (it imitate SSR)
    return { props: { product }, revalidate: 30 }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the Code

Comment: Could you add the `getStaticProps` code to the question? You probably need to handle those cases explicitly in there.

Comment: Thanks for your attention to my problem! I've added requested code in bottom of my question.

Comment: @juliomalves I'm added requested code in bottom of my question.

Comment: @Vince I've added code in my question:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trigger a 404 page by adding a check for `product` and return `notFound: true` if no product was found in `getStaticProps`.

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    await dbConnect()

    const product = await ProductModel.findById(params.id).lean()

    if (!product) {
        return {
            notFound: true
        }
    }

    product._id = product._id.toString()

    // revalidate set the time (in sec) of re-generate page (it imitate SSR)
    return { props: { product }, revalidate: 30 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this trick soon. But won't it hurt ISG?

Comment: In what way? As far as I'm aware, if you return a 404 that means the page won't exist, so it doesn't impact its re-generation.

Comment: Good, I'll try this method and give a review here.

Answer (score 1):

Make fallback “blocking” instead of true

Comment: Thanks for your attention! I've tried this way and read some documentation about `fallback: "blocking"`. This approach solves my problem, but what about users which will wait for the page without any "loading" information?

Comment: I'm not following what your concern is. You mean what happens to users who do not want to wait? For them, no props get returned which to mean, does not seem like a good idea. I now do blocking on all my pages.